# Debugging TypeScript in Visual Studio using Grunt / Gulp processed files

Tags: visual-studio-2013, gruntjs, typescript, gulp

I'm currently using the [Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification) to handle my bundling / minification in a greenfield TypeScript / Web API project.

In release mode I get reduced HTTP requests and minification.  In debug mode (where I do my development) I get the full Visual Studio debugging experience for my TypeScript code.  This is because Web Optimization in this situation is pointing directly at the js files created by the TypeScript and hooking back into the TypeScript thanks to the source map loveliness.  There are some rough edges around caching in debug mode as well as some limitations but **mostly** this is a pretty nice solution.

I'm now looking to switch to using either Grunt or Gulp to handle the bundling / minification (incidentally [I understand this is the direction that Visual Studio is planning to move anyway with ASP.Net vNext](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0M0zPgJ3HSftTAAHttA3JQU4vOjXFquF)).

I want to maintain the debug experience of being able to debug my TypeScript using source maps with this approach.  My assumption is that if I have a Grunt / Gulp job that (in debug) builds a folder with `*.js`, `*.map.js` and `*.ts` files that should preserve the Visual Studio TypeScript debugging experience.

I thought I'd check if there are any problems wrong with my underlying assumption.  Does this sound workable or am I starting myself down a blind alley?

I'm using Visual Studio 2013.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the `*.map.js` files and you attach to an internet explorer instance (with sourcemaps enabled in the IE debug tools) your breakpoints will work.